# when loading control Component with custom menuList in react select the input-field is getting shorter

Tags: infinite-scroll, react-select, react-virtualized, react-window, react-select-search

> `const MenuList = useCallback(
> children, ...props }) => {
> if (props.selectProps.inputValue && !props.options.length) {
> return (
> <div
> style={{
> backgroundColor: '#fff',
> border: '1px solid #fff',
> display: 'flex',
> flexWrap: 'wrap',
> justifyContent: 'center',
> alignItems: 'center',
> width: '99.4%',
> height: 300,
> fontSize: '1.2rem',
> }}
> >
>
> ##### No companies found
>
> )
> }
> const listRef = useRef(null)
> const childrenArray = Children.toArray(children)
> let currentIndex = 0
>
> useEffect(() => {
> if (searchValue.length > 0) {
> listRef?.current?.scrollToItem(0)
> else if ((currentIndex + pageSize) * page < childrenArray.length && searchValue.length === 0) {
> if (listRef.current) {
> listRef?.current?.scrollToItem((currentIndex + pageSize) * page)
> }
> }
> [currentIndex])
>
> return (
> <VirtualizedList
> listRef={(ref) => {
> listRef.current = ref
> }}
> width={100}
> listStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
> items={children}
> height={300}
> hasNextPage={props.selectProps.hasNextPage}
> isNextPageLoading={props.selectProps.isNextPageLoading}
> loadNextPage={props.selectProps.loadNextPage}
> itemSize={props.selectProps.itemSize}
> >
> index, style }) => {
> return children[index] ? (
> <div
> style={{
> ...style,
> backgroundColor: '#fff',
> border: '1px solid #fff',
> display: 'flex',
> flexWrap: 'wrap',
> alignItems: 'center',
> width: '99.4%',
> }}
> >
> {children[index]}
>
> ) : (
> <div
> style={{
> ...style,
> backgroundColor: '#fff',
> border: '1px solid #fff',
> display: 'flex',
> flexWrap: 'wrap',
> justifyContent: 'center',
> alignItems: 'center',
> width: '99.4%',
> }}
> >
>
> ##### Loading...
>
> )
> }}
>
> )
> },
> [companies.length],
> )
>
> const customStyles = {
> control: (baseStyles, states) => {
> return {
> ...baseStyles,
> border: `1px solid #858585`,
> fontSize: '.8rem !important',
> zIndex: '',
> }
> },
> option: (baseStyles, states) => {
> return {
> ...baseStyles,
> }
> },
> }
>
> return (
> <Box position="relative" sx={{ width: '300px' }}>
> <Select
> isClearable={true}
> label={'Select Company'}
> value={selectedCompany}
> onChange={handleSetSelectedCompany}
> options={searchValue.length > 0 ? searchValueArray : companies}
> hasNextPage={searchValue.length > 0 ? false : hasMore}
> isNextPageLoading={searchValue.length > 0 ? false : isLoading}
> loadNextPage={loadMoreRows}
> itemSize={() => 30}
> onInputChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e)}
> inputValue={searchValue}
> components={{
> Control: (props) => Control(props, 'Select Company', false),
> MenuList,
> }}
> />
>
> )
> }
>
> virtualized List Code
>
> import React from "react";
> import PropTypes from "prop-types";
> import { VariableSizeList as List } from "react-window";
> import InfiniteLoader from "react-window-infinite-loader";
>
> function VirtualizedList({
> children,
> hasNextPage,
> isNextPageLoading,
> items,
> loadNextPage,
> listStyle,
> itemSize,
> height,
> width,
> listRef
> }) {
> const itemCount = hasNextPage ? items.length + 1 : items.length;
> const loadMoreItems = isNextPageLoading ? () => undefined : loadNextPage;
> const isItemLoaded = index => !hasNextPage || index < items.length;
>
> return (
> <InfiniteLoader
> data-testId="infinite-loader"
> isItemLoaded={isItemLoaded}
> itemCount={itemCount}
> loadMoreItems={loadMoreItems}
>
> ```
> >
> ```
>
> onItemsRendered, ref }) => {
> return (
> <List
> ref={currentRef => {
> if (listRef) {
> listRef(currentRef);
> }
> ref(currentRef);
> }}
> width={width}
> height={height}
> itemCount={itemCount}
> itemSize={itemSize}
> style={listStyle}
> onItemsRendered={onItemsRendered}
> className="VirtualizedList-Component"
> >
> {listProps => children(listProps)}
>
> );
> }}
>
> );
> }
>
> VirtualizedList.propTypes = {
> hasNextPage: PropTypes.bool,
> isNextPageLoading: PropTypes.bool,
> items: PropTypes.array,
> loadMoreItems: PropTypes.func,
> listStyle: PropTypes.object,
> itemSize: PropTypes.func,
> height: PropTypes.number,
> width: PropTypes.number,
> listRef: PropTypes.func,
> children:PropTypes.any,
> loadNextPage:PropTypes.any,
> }; i tried everything according to my knowledge...but what's happening here...somehow when i am loading Control component along with a custom MenuList prop...it is preventing the default input-field to shrink because of which which my search value state is getting updated by only 1 single character at once. and if want to type another character i have to point the cursor again and this cycle is being repeated. any kind of help and Suggestions will be appreciated. thank you in advance.`